# |+| is a semigroup, why it needs a monoid implicit resolution

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scalaz, scalaz7

The aim of Semigroup is to make sure Associativity and closure
The aim of monoid is based on Semigroup and provide additional Identity.
When I use |+| semigroup appender, why I have define implicit monoid not implicit semigroup

Here is the code I am using reduceLeft which doesnt require the initial value

```
    val result1 = List(Staff("John", 36), Staff("Andrew", 30))
    val result2 = List(Staff("John", 40), Staff("Danny", 30))
    val result3 = List(Staff("Andrew", 30))
    val result4: List[Staff] = List()

    implicit val staffListSemigroup = new Monoid[List[Staff]] {

      override def zero: List[Staff] = Nil

      override def append(f1: List[Staff], f2: => List[Staff]): List[Staff] = {

        val mapSemigroup = f1.map(t => (t.name, t.numberOfTasks)).toMap |+| f2.map(t => (t.name, t.numberOfTasks)).toMap

        mapSemigroup.map(t => Staff(t._1, t._2)).toList

      }
    }

    val result = List(result1, result2, result3, result4).reduceLeft(_ |+| _)

    assert(result.size == 3)
```

if staffListSemigroup is Semigroup[List[Staff]], the compilation error is value |+| is not a member of List[SemigroupSpec.this.Staff]

Also, the definition of |+| is inside the Semigroup

```
final class SemigroupOps[F] private[syntax](val self: F)(implicit val F: Semigroup[F]) extends Ops[F] {
  ////
  final def |+|(other: => F): F = F.append(self, other)
  final def mappend(other: => F): F = F.append(self, other)
  final def ⊹(other: => F): F = F.append(self, other)
  ////
}
```

Many thanks in advance

**Edit**

followed by @Travis answer, I dont think it is correct. For the implicit value, the specific value will always override the generic one. Here is a code example I just wrote:

```
case class Foo(i : Int, s : String)
class Test[T] {
  def print = "print test"
}

implicit val test = new Test[Any]
implicit val testMoreSpecific = new Test[Foo] {
  override def print = "print Foo"
}

def doStuff[A](implicit test: Test[A]) = {
  test.print
}

doStuff[Foo] //it successfully print out print Foo
doStuff //compilation error, ambiguous implicit value found
```

Is that because in the Scalaz, no type specified in the method like Foo is not specified.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that there's already a `Semigroup` for `List[A]` for any `A`. You've defined a more specific instance for `List[Staff]`, which leads to an ambiguity, as you can see by asking for the instance:

```
scala> Semigroup[List[Staff]]
<console>:17: error: ambiguous implicit values:
 both method listMonoid in trait ListInstances of type [A]=> scalaz.Monoid[List[A]]
 and value staffListSemigroup of type => scalaz.Semigroup[List[Staff]]
 match expected type scalaz.Semigroup[List[Staff]]
              Semigroup[List[Staff]]
                       ^
```

You could jump through some hoops and try to keep the Scalaz-provided instance out of scope, but please don't!—it's potentially very confusing for other users and is a violation of [some basic good principles for working with type classes](http://blog.ezyang.com/2014/07/type-classes-confluence-coherence-global-uniqueness/). Instead you can write a wrapper for `List[Staff]` (a simple case class would do) and then provide an instance for that type.

---

For the sake of completeness, it's worth noting that the version with `Monoid` compiles because `Monoid` is more specific than `Semigroup` (see section 6.26.3 of the [language specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) for the rules that apply here, but be warned that they're kind of a mess).

Comment: Hey Travis, I dont think it is because ambiguous, because implicit value specific type can override generic ones, I add one example to clarify that.

Comment: @Cloudtech: But `listMonoid` doesn't provide a `Monoid[List[Any]]`—it provides a generic `Monoid[List[A]]` for whatever `A`.

Comment: So does that means we should never define implicit semigroup for the List ?

Comment: That depends on what you mean by "should". You _can_, if you keep Scalaz's `listMonoid` out of scope, and this may work just fine for you. In general it's a bad idea, though.

Comment: Yes, the code looks weird to exclude listMonoid. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Cloudtech: Just to be clear: the problem isn't only about the workaround "looking weird"—you won't necessarily always have control over what instance is in scope, and mixing and matching instances with different behavior can lead to very confusing bugs.